# Transforming PSObject Columns

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to "collapse" rows from a dataset which I'm creating. The values in the "Site" column are what I would like to have as columns.

Here is an example of what the table looks like now and what I would like for it to look like:

```
$RowA1 = @{ObjectPath="Setting1";CtrlValue="ABC";TestValue="DEF";Site="clientA"}
$RowA2 = @{ObjectPath="Setting2";CtrlValue="123";TestValue="456";Site="clientA"}
$RowA3 = @{ObjectPath="Setting1";CtrlValue="ABC";TestValue="GHI";Site="clientB"}
$RowA4 = @{ObjectPath="Setting2";CtrlValue="123";TestValue="789";Site="clientB"}
$Source = $RowA1,$RowA2,$RowA3,$RowA4
$Source | %({[PSCustomObject]$_}) | select ObjectPath,CtrlValue,TestValue,Site | Format-Table -AutoSize

Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------"

$RowB1 = @{ObjectPath="Setting1";CtrlValue="ABC";clientA="DEF";clientB="GHI"}
$RowB2 = @{ObjectPath="Setting2";CtrlValue="123";clientA="456";clientB="789"}
$Dest = $RowB1,$RowB2
$Dest | %({[PSCustomObject]$_}) | select ObjectPath,CtrlValue,clientA,clientB | Format-Table -AutoSize



ObjectPath CtrlValue TestValue Site   
---------- --------- --------- ----   
Setting1   ABC       DEF       clientA
Setting2   123       456       clientA
Setting1   ABC       GHI       clientB
Setting2   123       789       clientB


--------------------------------------------------------

ObjectPath CtrlValue clientA clientB
---------- --------- ------- -------
Setting1   ABC       DEF     GHI    
Setting2   123       456     789
```

1. How can I go about performing this type of transformation dynamically (there might also be a clientC in the first dataset)?
2. What is the name of this type of transformation (maybe partition)?

I could create the desired result set programmatically but I would like to use more query-style instructions in Powershell when working with datasets.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by query-style instructions.. You need to fix this "programmatically" AFAIK

Comment: Sorry, the word I meant to use was "procedural". I wanted to avoid using loops to create new objects and try to use selects, groups, joins etc. More sql style since I was working with a dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by properties that identify the group, then add the columns by looping through the group members. Ex:

```
$RowA1 = @{ObjectPath="Setting1";CtrlValue="ABC";TestValue="DEF";Site="clientA"}
$RowA2 = @{ObjectPath="Setting2";CtrlValue="123";TestValue="456";Site="clientA"}
$RowA3 = @{ObjectPath="Setting1";CtrlValue="ABC";TestValue="GHI";Site="clientB"}
$RowA4 = @{ObjectPath="Setting2";CtrlValue="123";TestValue="789";Site="clientB"}
$RowA5 = @{ObjectPath="Setting1";CtrlValue="ABC";TestValue="JKL";Site="clientC"}
$Source = $RowA1,$RowA2,$RowA3,$RowA4,$RowA5 | % ({[PSCustomObject]$_})

#Identifier-propteries
$idprop = "ObjectPath", "CtrlValue"

$Dest = $Source |
#Group objects that belong together using identifier-properties
Group-Object -Property $idprop | ForEach-Object {
    #Create new object with common properties
    $obj = $_.Group[0] | Select-Object $idprop

    #Add client-properties
    $_.Group | ForEach-Object {
        Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Site -Value $_.TestValue
    }

    #Output new "consolidated" object
    $obj

}

#PowerShell only displays the columns in the first object by default. Workaround: Specify all columns we want
#Find all propertynames in collection
$cols = $Dest | % { $_.psobject.properties } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Unique

#Output using Select-Object
$Dest | Select-Object -Property $cols
```

Output:

```
ObjectPath : Setting1
CtrlValue  : ABC
clientA    : DEF
clientB    : GHI
clientC    : JKL

ObjectPath : Setting2
CtrlValue  : 123
clientA    : 456
clientB    : 789
clientC    : 


$Dest | Format-Table -Property $cols -AutoSize

ObjectPath CtrlValue clientA clientB clientC
---------- --------- ------- ------- -------
Setting1   ABC       DEF     GHI     JKL    
Setting2   123       456     789
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.